# Django. Render model parameters by js

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I create simple app. Main page of this app display all objects by one model, and when I click on object, js script render object parameters in `<div>`
I use some ugly logic for this solution: add all parametres with html tags in model method

```
class SimpleObject(models.Model):
    param1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    param2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def object_info(self):
        param1 = '<p>' + self.param1 + '</p>'
        param2 = '<p>' + self.param2 + '</p>'
        return param1 + param2
```

send it by ListView:

```
class SimpleObjectList(ListView):
    model = SimpleObject
```

and render like this(with bootstrap):

```
<div class="col-md-4">
{% for object in object_list %}
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="object_item" name="{{object.object_info}}">
            <a href="#">{{object.param1}}</a></li>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 object_info">
</div>


$('.object_item').click(function(){
    var simple_object = this;
    $('.object_info').empty();      
    $('.object_info').append($(simple_object).attr('name'));
});
```

It looks like I want, but I definatly sure, have beter solution for this problem. Can you help me with some best practise for work with models field by js

*How it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load just part of the DOM, which should be used to show the newly fetched data from server.

the idea is:

```
<div>
  {% for object in object_list %}
     <a class="obj_cls" data-object_id="{{ object.id }}"></a>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="snippet_wrapper">
  {% include "html_snippet_only_for_this_part.html" %}
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function(){
  $('.obj_cls').on('click', function () {
    var object_id = $(this).data('object_id');
    $('.snippet_wrapper').html('').load("/"+object_id, function () {        
    });
  });
 });
</script>
```

and the view with url `/PK/` where `object_id` is the ID of clicked object should do this:

```
def PartyDetailView(DetailView):
    model = YourModel
    template_name = "html_snippet_only_for_this_part.html"
```

and the content of `html_snippet_only_for_this_part.html` is just:

```
<div>
  {{ object.name }} etc etc... 
</div>
```

hope, this helps! :)